# Using octopress with emacs org-mode for blogging

Tags: emacs, org-mode, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

Is there any example of using Org-mode with octopress for blogging? I want to use org-mode for all the blog posts and export it to html. I understand this is possible, is there any example for this to learn and do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have begun migrating to Octopress as well. Being an Org-mode user, I was interested in the same thing. Here is a link I found that might prove useful to you: http://jaderholm.com/blog/blogging-with-org-mode-and-octopress

Answer (score 1):

Some time back I wrote an article on this topic: http://www.railsonmaui.com/blog/2013/04/27/octopress-setup-with-github-and-org-mode/index.html

This uses the orgmode-octopress emacs plugin:
https://github.com/craftkiller/orgmode-octopress and http://blog.paphus.com/blog/2012/08/01/introducing-octopress-blogging-for-org-mode/

Unfortunately, this does not work with Emacs 24.3 and org-mode v8. :-(

There's a different org-mode octopress package (available in the emacs package manager): https://github.com/yoshinari-nomura/org-octopress

Unfortunately, the documentation on that is sparse. I plan to update my blog and this answer once I get a good solution to work with emacs 24.3 and org-mode v8.